# Twython - How can I speed up getting a user's followers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, twython

I'm trying to get a list of a really big twitter account's followers using Twython. I have code that will do this, but I have to insert pauses to avoid the API's rate limits. At the fastest speed I've found that avoids the rate limits, it will take my code over 20 days of continuous running to go through all the accounts. Here's the relevant code:

```
twitter = Twython(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, 
           access_token_secret)
account_followers = twitter.cursor(twitter.get_followers_list ,screen_name = 
                                   "example")
BATCH_SIZE = 300
batch_left = BATCH_SIZE
count = 0

for follower in account_followers:
    batch_left -= 1
    count += 1
    print(count)
    if batch_left == 0:
        batch_left = BATCH_SIZE
        print("sleeping now")
        time.sleep(90)
```

The rest of the code is just some processing of my results that don't make any additional requests to the Twitter API.

Does anyone know of a method to make a process like this faster? 
Apologies if the answer is very simple, I have limited coding expertise!

Comment: why don't you just use length method instead of counting users in a for loop?

Comment: The count variable was just for the purpose of figuring out how long getting all the followers would take. I probably shouldn't have even left it in the question!